# Mockery OneToMany mock and check if objects are the same

Tags: php, unit-testing, doctrine-orm, phpunit, mockery

I have a piece of code, that I want to test. The function I need to test, looks like this:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     * @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException
     */
    public function validate()
    {
        if (null !== $this->getIssuer() &&
            null !== $this->getPurchaser() &&
            $this->getIssuer() === $this->getPurchaser()) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException('issuer_same_as_purchaser');
        }

        // Payment date should be equal or larger than issue date. You're not supposed to issue an
        // invoice in the future with payment date equal to now.
        // Todo: This should be optional - in some cases, it may be ok to do this.
        // Todo: Maybe we should change the payment date to issue date instead of throwing an exception?
        // Maybe make it optional?
        if (null !== $this->paymentDate
            && null !== $this->issueDate
            && $this->paymentDate < $this->issueDate) {
            // Payment date cannot be before issue date
            throw new BadRequestHttpException('payment_date.before_issue_date');
        }
    }
```

Now, I need to get `$this->getIssuer() === $this->getPurchaser()` to be equal. I mock it like this:

```
    public function testValidate()
    {
        $invoice = new Invoice();
        $contractor = new Contractor();
        $issuer = \Mockery::mock($contractor, ['getId' => '123']);

        /** @var Invoice $invoiceIssuerSameAsPurchaser */
        $invoiceIssuerSameAsPurchaser = \Mockery::mock(
            $invoice,
            [
                'getIssuer' => '123',
                'getPurchaser' => '123'
            ]
        );

        $invoiceIssuerSameAsPurchaser->validate();
    }
```

When I launch the `validate()` function, it doesn't even get into the `if` because I'm checking if `getIssuer` and `getPurchaser` are not null. How can I convince PHP, that there are objects set under those two functions?